# Qual è il significato di "adombrare" in questo brano?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel libro *L'affaire Moro* di Leonardo Sciascia ho letto:

> Lo Stato di cui si preoccupa, lo Stato che occupa i suoi pensieri fino all’ossessione, io credo l’**abbia adombrato** nella parola «famiglia». Che non è una mera sostituzione – alla parola Stato la parola famiglia – ma come un allargamento di significato: dalla propria famiglia alla famiglia del partito e alla famiglia degli italiani di cui il partito rappresenta, anche di quelli che non lo votano, la «volontà generale».

La persona di cui si sta parlando è Aldo Moro.
Non capisco il significato del verbo "adombrare" in questo passaggio, malgrado l'abbia cercato in alcuni dizionari. Me lo potreste spiegare?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il significato pertinente qui è quello che la [definizione del Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/adombrare/) dà come 2.b:

> Rappresentare senza rilievo o colore, esprimere velatamente, o in modo incompiuto, inadeguato: *sentimenti che si possono appena a.*; *non potrei che imperfettamente a. i pensieri di quella mente sublime*; per estens., rappresentare in genere: *quanto in più selvaggio Loco mi trovo ..., Tanto più bella il mio pensier l’adombra* (Petrarca).

Quindi che lo Stato viene adombrato nella parola “famiglia” significa che questa parola allude allo Stato, fa pensare allo Stato senza che la persona di cui si parla (Aldo Moro?) lo menzioni esplicitamente.

Comment: La persona di cui si sta parlando è, effettivamente,  Aldo Moro: ho aggiunto questa informazione al testo della domanda.

Answer (score 0):

[Adombrare](http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/A/adombrare.php) è usato in senso figurato col significato di preoccupare, turbare:

> - fig. Insospettirsi, turbarsi, offendersi: *si adombra per qualsiasi contrarietà.*

Garzanti

- La parola famiglia, nel brano riferita al senso dello Stato in senso ampio, adombra, preoccupa i suoi pensieri.

Comment: Non è questo il senso, tra l'altro perché questo uso di “adombrare” è solo al riflessivo (“adombrarsi”) e non se ne potrebbe fare il passivo.